# scroll bar initial range

Tags: c, winapi, scrollbar, msdn

I am currently learning about scroll bars, the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says the following:

> The initial range depends on the scroll bar. Standard scroll bars have
>   an initial range of 0 through 100;

Wouldn't this mean that there are 101 values to set for the position of the scroll box? Or is this a typo and they mean 0 through 99?

Comment: The range describes the total size of the contents of the element (be it a list, an edit control, whatever) being scrolled, however the valid positions the scrollbar can return depend on the page size that can be displayed at any one time.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the range is `[min, max]`, the page is `page`,
the possible value for position should be `[min, max - page + 1]`

For example, 
suppose `min = 0, max = 100, page = 3`,

[image]

the valid range for thumb position is `[0, 98]`.

Answer (score -1):

The document states - 0 through 100, Windows API is wonderful.

This site might be more helpful as it explains the setup process very clearly.

http://www.functionx.com/win32/controls/scrollbars.htm

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): *"Provide context for links: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."*